# Get the Results of an Include in a String in PHP?

Tags: php, include

Let's say file test.php looks like this:

```
<?php
echo 'Hello world.';
?>
```

I want to do something like this:

```
$test = include('test.php');

echo $test;

// Hello world.
```

Can anyone point me down the right path?

Edit:

My original goal was to pull PHP code intermingled with HTML out of a database and process it. Here's what I ended up doing:

```
// Go through all of the code, execute it, and incorporate the results into the content
while(preg_match('/<\?php(.*?)\?>/ims', $content->content, $phpCodeMatches) != 0) {
    // Start an output buffer and capture the results of the PHP code
    ob_start();
    eval($phpCodeMatches[1]);
    $output = ob_get_clean();

    // Incorporate the results into the content
    $content->content = str_replace($phpCodeMatches[0], $output, $content->content);
}
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Using [output buffering](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.ob-start.php) is the best bet.

```
ob_start();
include 'test.php';
$output = ob_get_clean();
```

PS: Remember that you can nest output buffers to your hearts content as well if needed.

Comment: save a line: `$output = ob_get_clean();` ;-)

Comment: Why use output buffers at all? ``test.php`` should return the value, then you should simply get the value using ``$output = include('test.php'); ``

Answer (score 10):

test.php

```
<?php

return 'Hello World';

?>
```

---

```
<?php

$t = include('test.php');

echo $t;

?>
```

As long as the included file has a return statement it will work.

Answer (score 4):

You can also have the included file return the output, rather than print it. Then you can grab it into a variable, just like you do in your second example.

```
<?php
    return 'Hello world.';
?>
```

Answer (score -5):

```
$test = file_get_contents('test.php');
echo $test; //Outputs "Hello world.";
```

Comment: That won't parse the PHP in test.php, just print it. And doing an eval() on the string would be slower than using an include with output buffering.