# PHP require return echo?

Tags: php

Is it possible to require a php file and get all the things that's echo'ed to be returned and stored into a variable?

Example:

```
//file1.php
// let's say $somevar = "hello world"
<p><?php echo $somevar; ?></p>


//file2.php
$file1 = getEchoed("file1.php");
// I know getEchoed don't exist, but i'm unsure how to do it.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the Results of an Include in a String in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814182/get-the-results-of-an-include-in-a-string-in-php)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use output buffering:

```
ob_start();
require('somefile.php');
$data = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: oops, changed it to use the correct function. always confusing those two.

Comment: Don't I need to ob_end() as well, if i want to turn it off?

Comment: No. `ob_get_clean() essentially executes both ob_get_contents() and ob_end_clean().`

Answer (score 1):

[Output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) can do what you need.

```
ob_start();
require("file1.php");
$file1 = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ob_start();
include('file1.php');
$contents = ob_get_clean();
```

The output from file1.php is now stored in the variable $contents.

Answer (score 0):

[Output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php):

```
<?php

ob_start();

require 'file1.php';

$var_buffer = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();

echo $var_buffer;

?>
```