# PHPMailer: how can i get PHP code to evaluate in my templates?

Tags: php, templates, phpmailer

i'm using PHPMailer to send emails and, naturally, i'm using templates to do so based on variable conditions.  however, i need to be able to use PHP in the template itself before sending it.  i have some arrays i need to iterate out into HTML lists, and the arrays are always different depending on the circumstances.

```php
//  all variables are pulled from the $_POST array
$list = $_POST['listArray'];
$numberOfDays = $_POST['numberOfDays'];    //  90
... and more

//  create the instance
  $mail = new PHPMailer;
  // $mail->isSMTP();  //  requires commenting out to work... don't know why yet...
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
  $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
  //  host server (using Mailhog for testing)
  $mail->Host = '127.0.0.1';
  $mail->Port = 25;
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->Username = EMAILUSERNAME;
  $mail->Password = EMAILPASSWORD;

  $mail->setFrom($fromEmail, $fromName);
  $mail->addReplyTo('blarg@blarg.blarg');
  $mail->addAddress($to);
  $mail->Subject = $subject;
  $mail->Body = file_get_contents(__DIR__.'\${numberOfDays}days.php');  //  90days.php

  //  send the email and check for errors
  if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Mail error: '. $mail->ErrorInfo;
  } else {
    echo 'Message sent Successfully';
  }
```

this is the `90days.php` file:

```php
<p>As a result of our inspections at <?php echo $bldgName; ?>, 
 the following code violations have been identified:</p>

<?php foreach ($list as $key => $value) { 
  echo '<ul>';
   foreach ($value as $vkey => $vvalue) {
    echo '<li>'.$vvalue.'</li>';    
  }
  echo '</ul>';
 } ?>

<p>As this is an email regarding these deficiencies, you now have</p>
<h1><?php echo $numberOfDays ?></h1>
<p>When responding, please use the following in your subject line:</p>
<h2> <?php echo $subjectLine; ?> </h2>
<p>Thank you for your prompt attention to these matters.</p>
```

what winds up in my email inbox is just raw plaintext of the HTML/PHP.  the PHP variables aren't being evaluated.  when i run the `file_get_contents()`, i was expecting the PHP to be evaluated when it came in, like an `include`.  if i change `$mail->Body` to `$mail->msgHTML`, same deal, but at least it comes through as HTML, not plaintext of HTML.

so! how do i get the PHP to evaluate in this template when it's brought in to the PHPMailer object?

Comment: _“when i run the `file_get_contents()`, i was expecting the PHP to be evaluated when it came in, like an `include`.”_ - you expected wrong then. That is not what file_get_contents does (the clue is kinda in the name there already, with _contents_.) Using include with output buffering would be one solution to this.

Comment: (Using include with return would also work, but then you would need to modify your mail templates accordingly, so that you gather all the output in a string variable, so that it can be returned.)

Comment: can you show me how that would look?  `$message = include(90days.'php');` doesn't seem likely to work.  or would i wrap it in `ob_start()`?

Comment: How using include with return works, is explained in the manual for include.

Comment: How to use output buffering for this, is something you could have researched yourself - “php capture include output” typed into Google, leads to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814182/get-the-results-of-an-include-in-a-string-in-php in no time.

Comment: i had done the research.  i was asking for optimal method.  i guess i should have been clearer on that.  i know i can use either, but which one is better in this use-case?

Comment: Using output buffering means you don’t have to change anything about your existing mail templates, so probably that one.

Comment: perfect.  thank you.